Op-amp with significant noise
I have the circuit below on breadboard. (Photodiode connected to op-amp in Transimpedance configuration)
With LF351N (placed on the breadboard) as op-amp I'm getting nice signal on oscilloscope
However when I swap it with LTC6228 (soldered onto PCB board and connected via jumper wires), a significant noise pops up.
Can you suggest me where I'm doing wrong? Does opAmp amplify the noise itself somewhere?





It is obviously not noise, but an oscillation. Have you tried a slightly larger C1, or putting C1 closer to the opamp pins? How much capacitance does your photodiode have?

@tobalt I'm using BPW21 photodiode. It has 1.2nF capacitance but the problem is that I do have this signal even though photodiode is not connected

@LifeIsBeatiful, Which type of power supply is the +5V and -5V coming from?

@Vincent this one

@LifeIsBeatiful, As a test, can you replace your power supply with batteries?

@Vincent I got the reason. I'll give it a try. thank you ref

@Vincent tried but no change. i have put everything onto pcb board though. now I have only 5mV noise which is not sinusoidal. Any recommendation to remove it as well?


LTC6228 (soldered onto PCB board and connected via jumper wires)

A few pointers: -

Try removing the photodiode to prevent overhead lighting influencing the noise
Breadboard will be poo for the LTC6228 (I'm trying not to curse or spit)
An LTC6228 connected with jumper wires to breadboard is double poo
You need to have supply decouplers on the power pins
You need to have a stable supply that isn't derived from an unearthed wall-wart

Note this about the LTC6228: -
High speed and RF board layout techniques should be
used due to the very high speeds of the signals involved.
For the LTC6228 SOIC-8 package option, the feedback
should be taken from the FB pin rather than from the
output pin, to reduce signal trace length.

Stray capacitances at the –IN and +IN pins should be
made as low as possible to reduce stability degradation.
For example, ground or supply planes on a PCB should
not encompass the areas just beneath the input pins.

For single supply applications, it is recommended that high
quality 0.1µF||1000pF ceramic bypass capacitors be placed
directly between each V+ pin and its closest V– pin with
short connections. The V– pins (including the Exposed Pad)
should be tied directly to a low impedance ground plane
with minimal routing. For dual (split) power supplies, it is
recommended that additional high quality 0.1µF||1000pF
ceramic capacitors be used to bypass V+ pins to ground
and V– pins to ground, again with minimal routing.

I can imagine that all relevant instructions in this DS extract are unheeded.

Many thanks Andy. I have soldered board and feedback circuit now on the pcb board. I'm still getting sinusoidal signal. I will try to go through other suggestions that were mentioned in the datasheet.

@LifeIsBeatiful the sinusoidal signal at 19.379 MHz does look like instability. Check the decoupling capacitors. It's a really fast op-amp and little things do matter. Come back and let me know what happens but, for now, if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

decoupling capacitor on Vcc got OpAmp working. Decoupling capacitor of Vcc-  had no effect . However I'm still getting noisy signal. At a few instances upon playing with Inp+ to ground (i.e pushing jumper wire etc) made noise gone away. Upon this I have soldered In+ directly to ground. but ended up with no change. currently everything is on pcb board and I'm still getting that noise.

Decoupling capacitors and having everything on the pcb reduced the sinusoidal significantly down to 5mV. Can you please advise me further how I can reduce this small amount?

@LifeIsBeatiful we are at the point of very diminishing returns using comments to solve problems. What I advise is that you start a new post and show images of the LTC6228 as you currently have it. Show all wiring and detail the power supply. Show scope shots of the 5 mV ripple also. Note: this cannot be done in comments hence why I recommend a new post. Apart from anything else, it will open up the problem to the full audience of engineers and so it makes sense for you to go down this route. Please also explain that your new question is a follow-on from this post and provide a link.
